# python code runs on idle but doesn't run on spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from pandastable import Table , TableModel

df = TableModel.getSampleData()

f = Frame(Tk())
f.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
Table(f, dataframe=df, showstatusbar=True).show()
```

This code will display dataframe in new window. It works on idle, idlex. But doesn't work on spyder ide. It doesn't give any error either. Please help me if it is possible to run it on spyder, ipython notebook.

(spyder have an in built feature to open dataframe in new window, I am just curious to know why this code is not working)

I am using anaconda python 3.5, windows 10

Comment: normally `tkinter` requires you to call `mainloop()` to display anything, there are some IDEs that let you get away with just running it at the end but I'd recommend just calling `tkinter.mainloop()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run your code in Spyder's *IPython console*, but before doing it, you need to run this command:

```
In [1]: %gui tk
```

After that, you should be able to see your dataframe displayed as expected.

*Note*: The previous command activates the Tk event loop, which is necessary to be able to display widgets/applications based on Tk.